# Strip first two bytes from a string in python

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

I need to remove the Byte Order Mark from a string. I already have the code to find the BOM but now I need to remove it from the actual string.

To give you an example. The BOM is `feff` and has a length of 2 bytes which means that the first two bytes of the string should not occur in the final string. However, when I use the Python string stripping, too much is stripped from the string.

Code snippet:

```
print len(bom)
print as_hex(bom)
print string
print as_hex(string)
string = string[len(bom):]
print string
print as_hex(string)
```

Output:

```
2
feff
Organ
feff4f7267616e
rgan
7267616e
```

What I hope to get is:

```
2
feff
Organ
feff4f7267616e
Organ
4f7267616e
```

The `as_hex()` function just prints the characters as hex (`"".join('%02x' % ord(c) for c in bytes`)).

Comment: What is the `bom` variable you are using?  It seems to have the wrong length.

Comment: have you tried printing `len(bom)`?

Comment: 4 hexadecimal characters are actually 2 bytes. why are you striping 4?

Comment: How is it possible that `as_hex(string[:4])` is printing 10 characters (5 bytes)?

Comment: @Triptych I think that Python counts characters, not bytes. It is the actual output of my code.

Comment: Strange stuff is going on in your code.  Please post a complete, self-contained runnable example that includes sample data.

Comment: @BrenBarn There is a lot of code around this. I'll add it as soon as I have boiled it down to something executable.

Comment: @dominik I'm quite sure that if you add a `print string` by the beginning will already clarify a bunch.

Comment: @Rubens I posted some more output.

Comment: Use the codecs module, it contains everything you need to deal with those pesky BOMs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a unicode string object. (If you're using Python 3 you certainly do, since it's the only kind of string.) Your as_hex function isn't printing out "fe" for the first character and "ff" for the second. It's printing out "feff" for the first unicode character in the string. For example (Python 3):

```
>>> mystr = "\ufeffHello world."
>>> mystr[0]
'\ufeff'
>>> '%02x' % ord(mystr[0])
'feff'
```

You either need to remove just one unicode character, or to store your string in a `bytes` object instead and remove two bytes.

(This doesn't explain why len(bom) is 2, and I can't tell without seeing more of your code. I'd guess that bom is a `list` or a `bytes` object, not a unicode string.)

---

My answer above assumes Python 3, but I've realised from your print statements that you're using Python 2. Based on that, I'd guess that `bom` is an ASCII string while `string` is a unicode string. If you use `print repr(x)` instead of `print x` it will let you tell the difference between unicode and ASCII strings.

Comment: This is what I was thinking too.  Note also, though, that it doesn't make sense to have the BOM in the unicode string, so there's probably a problem somewhere earlier where the string is created.  A BOM is only meaningful in an encoded string.

Comment: Actually isn't a BOM for indicating the endianness (byte order) of a text file or stream, not a string? Also, it can be more than 2 bytes long -- for example for UTF-8 it's the byte sequence `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`.

Comment: Your answer brought me to a solution. I have to do `string = bytearray(string, encoding=self.encoding)[len(bom):].decode(self.encoding)`

Comment: @martineau Yes, 2 is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the right codec and the BOM will be handled for you.  Decoding with `utf-8-sig` and `utf16` will remove a leading BOM if present.  Encoding with them will add the BOM.  If you do not want a BOM then use `utf-8`, `utf-16le` or `utf-16be`.

You typically should decode to Unicode when reading text data into a program, and encode to bytes when writing to file, console, socket, etc.

```
unicode_str = u'test'
utf8_w_bom = unicode_str.encode('utf-8-sig')
utf16_w_bom = unicode_str.encode('utf16')
utf8_wo_bom = unicode_str.encode('utf-8')
utf16_wo_bom = unicode_str.encode('utf-16le')
print repr(utf8_w_bom)
print repr(utf16_w_bom)
print repr(utf8_wo_bom)
print repr(utf16_wo_bom)
print repr(utf8_w_bom.decode('utf-8-sig'))
print repr(utf16_w_bom.decode('utf16'))
print repr(utf8_wo_bom.decode('utf-8-sig'))
print repr(utf16_wo_bom.decode('utf16'))
```

Output:

```
'\xef\xbb\xbftest'
'\xff\xfet\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00'
'test'
't\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00'
u'test'
u'test'
u'test'
u'test'
```

Note that on decode `utf16` will assume the native byte order if there is no BOM.